# Custom Walking Tracks + Directions Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

So far I have successfully integrated Mapbox GL JS + Mapbox GL-directions in my angular web application. The only issue is all my tracks are private walking tracks that are not part of the system and I'd like to give directions to users. I know in OSM you can create custom roads/tracks, but I believe this would be public for all. Is it possible to do something similar with Mapbox. Basically add custom streets/tracks in mapbox and use them with Mapbox GL Directions?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your question is: "does the Mapbox Directions API support third-party data that doesn't exist in Mapbox (OpenStreetMap-derived) public datasources?"

No, it doesn't.